# Left Join em SQL

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT SUM(TAXAS) FROM DOCUMENTO
LEFT JOIN PARCELAS PARCELA IN
(PARCELA.CODE = DOCUMENTO.CODE)
WHERE PARCELAS.FATURADAS = TRUE
```

Estou recebendo um erro de sintaxe que não consigo resolver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(DOC.TAXAS) FROM DOCUMENTOS DOC
LEFT JOIN PARCELAS PARCELA ON
(PARCELA.CODE = DOC.CODE)
WHERE PARCELAS.FATURADAS = 1
```

Você colocou IN quando deveria ser ON e deve ser 1 no lugar de true
Essa do where eu não tinha percebido, então pode dar como correta a resposta do Ricardo

Comment: Obrigado!
Eu não percebi, que vergonha..

Answer (score 4):

Tem dois erros no seu seu script:

1) `LEFT JOIN PARCELAS PARCELA IN` 
deve ser: `LEFT JOIN PARCELAS PARCELA ON`

Documentação: https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx

2) `WHERE PARCELAS.FATURADAS = TRUE` deve ser: `WHERE PARCELAS.FATURADAS = 1`

Campos `bit` são comparados com 0 (falso) ou 1 (verdadeiro)

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Melhor escrever sua sugestão como uma resposta adicional.